# NativeScript Vue - Android Build error under Windows 10 (ns build android ...)

Tags: android, build, nativescript

while building a simple NativeScript Application I got an Error during running this command:

ns build android --release --key-store-path  --key-store-password --key-store-alias --key-store-alias-password --aab

Error is:

```
Updating runtime package.json with configuration values...
Project successfully prepared (android)
Building project...
Gradle build...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'W:\XXX\app\platforms\android\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'W:\XXX\app\platforms\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)

 [...]

        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 748ms
Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
```

ns preview command worked perfectly

I'm developing on Windows 10.

Tried so much and searched a lot noting worked ...
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gradle version might be incompatible with your java version. Try installing an other version of java to resolve the issue.